# What Type of Differential Equation is $ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x(x-y)} $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, terminology

What type of differential equation is this?

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x(x-y)}
$$

I am stuck on this problem and can't seem to find any solution for it. Is it separable, homogeneous, exact, linear, or Bernoulli? Can anyone help?

Comment: Assuming that $y$ is a function of $x$ then its a first order non-linear ODE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Switching variables makes to problem looking easier
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x(x-y)}\implies \frac{dx}{dy}=x(x-y)$$So, asssuming $x\neq 0$
$$\frac 1 x \frac{dx}{dy}-x=-y$$

Comment: Ah I see, and then I can multiply by x and it will become a Bernoulli Equation.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{dx}{dy} = x(x-y) = x^2 - xy$, so it is [Bernoulli equation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/bernoullis-equation/) with respect to $x$ as function of $y$.